# Collection with integer, need to increase and decrease it on itself

Tags: java, collections, task

I have a task and I have some problems with it - hard to change a mindset i guess.

I need to create a collection, which keep integers and must perform such functions as:

1. Add and remove elements by its index and value (okay, i think it can be `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, am I right?)
2. In case if element will be added other elements must be increased by a value of added element.
3. In case if element will be removed other elements must be decreased by a value of added element.

Last two functions..I have no clues how to make it. Probably some of you can show me a direction, where I need to move and what I need to do?

In my mind I need to create `LinkedList` (it allows me to remove elements by its index and value) and use some wrapped types for list. But how?

---

**UPDATE**

To clarify (from comments), this is the desired result of calling `add()` and `remove()`:

```java
   add(1): [1]
   add(2): [3, 2]                  // Existing values are incremented
   add(3): [6, 5, 3]
   add(4): [10, 9, 7, 4]
   add(0): [10, 9, 7, 4, 0]
   add(5): [15, 14, 12, 9, 5, 5]
remove(3): [15, 14, 12, 9, 5, 5]   // Value not found, so no change
remove(9): [6, 5, 3, -4, -4]       // All values are decremented
remove(5): [1, -2, -9, -9]
```

Comment: _...increased by a value of added element..._ Which elements and which values?

Comment: for example if you added 1 to list and after you add 2, you should do 1+2, if you will next add 3 you will have to add 3+3, 2+3..

Comment: So if you have `[ 1, 2 ]` and you add 3 then 4 you get `[ 8, 9, 7, 4 ]` so if you remove 7 (you can't remove 3 as it's not there) you get `[ 1, 2, -3 ]` ?

Comment: If so the last two function are a matter of looping over the elements before adding or after removing and add/subtract as required.

Comment: `[1, 2]`... It must be `[3, 2]` or? o.O

Answer (score 1):

I would use an ArrayList. You can add elements in a specific index with

```
add(index, value)
```

You can remove elements by index with

```
remove(index)
```

For the second function, you can iterate the full ArrayList and add the value of the new element. After that, you add it to the ArrayList. For the third function you do it the opposite way: fist remove it and then you decrease its value to the remainig elements.

Last thing, remember you shouldn't (in fact I think you can't) remove an element of the ArrayList while you iterate it. So if you want to remove an element by its value, you can iterate the ArrayList keeping the indexes of the elements you want to remove, and then remove them. Hope it helps.

Comment: Up-voting, even though your last paragraph is wrong. You can remove while iterating, *if* you use the [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) method of the [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). Also, for the incrementing part, you can use the [`set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set-E-) method of [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get familiar with Java API Collection first, when you do that I'm pretty sure you will be able to resolve what you want.
I recommend this site: http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util

Comment: But i think it could be a problem with algorithm than with collections. I did my researches there, but i still do not understand.. Maybe i did bad researches, but could you give me a hint?

Comment: So I think you put the wrong tags on your question.
I don't understand your question very well, what I could see you don't need to use any Collection to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you don't need to change the elements in your collection to implement addition and subtraction (from all elements):

You could store in a variable (lets call it `diff`) the difference between the elements in the collection and the required result and update `diff` each time you add or remove an element.

Note that when you add an element, you probably have to alter the added element according to `diff`.

Example:

adding `1` to the array: `[0]`, `diff=1`, array + diff: `[1]`

adding `2` to the array: `[0, -1]`, `diff=3` , array + diff: `[3, 2]`

adding `3` to the array: `[0, -1, -3]`, `diff=6`, array + diff: `[6, 5, 3]`

removing `5` from array (actually removing `5-diff`): `[0, -3]`, `diff=1`, array + diff: `[1,-2]`

Comment: That won't work, because `diff` doesn't apply to all values. E.g. add `1` results in `[1]`, then add `2` results in `[3, 2]`, then add `3` results in `[6, 5, 3]`, and so forth.

Comment: exactly! And i do not understand how to make it!;(

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov See [answer by Eric](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40331114/5221149). He describes how to do it.

Comment: @Andreas that's why I added the last paragraph... in order to apply `diff` to all values, you need to subtract `diff` from a newly added value. I'll add an example shortly

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use ArrayList no need to use linkedlist in your use case
2. you need to iterate over the list and sum the integer with the existing values and add it to the list
3. you need to check if the list contains the Integer before removing it

you can try this code

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        addAndSum(list, 1);
        System.out.println(list);
        addAndSum(list, 2);
        System.out.println(list);
        addAndSum(list, 3);
        System.out.println(list);
        addAndSum(list, 4);
        System.out.println(list);
        addAndSum(list, 0);
        System.out.println(list);
        addAndSum(list, 5);
        System.out.println(list);
        removeAndSustract(list, 3);
        System.out.println(list);
        removeAndSustract(list, 9);
        System.out.println(list);
        removeAndSustract(list, 5);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private static void addAndSum(List<Integer> list, Integer i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++)
            list.set(j, list.get(j) + i);
        list.add(i);
    }

    private static void removeAndSustract(List<Integer> list, int i) {
        if (list.contains(i)) {
            list.remove((Integer) i);
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++)
                list.set(j, list.get(j) - i);
        }
    }
```

the output

```
[1]
[3, 2]
[6, 5, 3]
[10, 9, 7, 4]
[10, 9, 7, 4, 0]
[15, 14, 12, 9, 5, 5]
[15, 14, 12, 9, 5, 5]
[6, 5, 3, -4, -4]
[1, -2, -9, -9]
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much! Now i understand some logic of how i should do that! But what about adding and removing by index and value?

Comment: in the exemple I give the removing is by value, because I did a cast to integer before removing the int the avoid removing the Integer with the index i, but removing the Integer with the value i